# Querying Array Positions in MongoDB?

Tags: java, mongodb

I am using Java Driver for mongoDB. I have a document which contains, `AlbumName`, `PreviewSize`, `ThumbSize`, `_id` & `Comments`. `PreviewSize` & `ThumbSize` are array. I want to know how can i query this document and get any specific array value.

To be more clear, my document is like this,

```
Document : { "AlbumName" : "Test" , "PreviewSize" : [ 
{ "ImageName" : "tom_and_jerry_guns.jpg" , "BinaryImage" : <Binary Data>} , 
{ "ImageName" : "Tom_and_Jerry,_Cartoons.jpg" , "BinaryImage" : <Binary Data>} , 
{ "ImageName" : "TomJerry2_468x342.jpg" , "BinaryImage" : <Binary Data>} , 
{ "ImageName" : "tom_and_jerry-5405.jpg" , "BinaryImage" : <Binary Data>}] , 

"ThumbSize" : [ { "ImageName" : "tom_and_jerry_guns.jpg" , "BinaryImage" : <Binary Data>} , 
{ "ImageName" : "Tom_and_Jerry,_Cartoons.jpg" , "BinaryImage" : <Binary Data>} , 
{ "ImageName" : "TomJerry2_468x342.jpg" , "BinaryImage" : <Binary Data>} , 
{ "ImageName" : "tom_and_jerry-5405.jpg" , "BinaryImage" : <Binary Data>}] , 

"_id" : { "$oid" : "4cef03b44613b5ba2d51a7b8"} , "comments" : [ ]}
```

How shall i get the `TomJerry2_468x342.jpg` and its `<Binary Data>` from `PreviewSize`.

I am new to mongoDB. I dont know whether its possible or not. I just constructed this document and i am able to update this document with new images. I learnt this from [this](http://files.meetup.com/930480/MongoDB.pdf) presentation.

My question how can i able to get any specific `<Binary Data>` when i have its name?

Any Suggestions would be more appreciative!

Thanks!!!

**Update**

For example: // The code i tried,

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject(); 
BasicDBObject field = new BasicDBObject(); 
field.put("PreviewSize", 1); 
DBCursor cursor = coll.find(query, field); 
while(cursor.hasNext()){ 
     BasicDBObject result = (BasicDBObject) cursor.next(); 
     int i = result.size();
     System.out.println("Result Size: "+i);
     System.out.println(result);

     int i = result.size(); 
     String imageName = (String) ((BasicDBList)result.get("PreviewSize")).get("ImageName"); 
     System.out.println("Result Size: "+i+" Image Name :"+imageName); 
     byte[] imageByte = (byte[]) ((BasicDBList) result.get("PreviewSize")).get("BinaryImage"); 
     if(imageByte != null){System.out.println("Wow! Great!!! Its Coming!!!");} 
     else{System.out.println("Try Another Way!");} 
}// I am not sure this is exist(I am new to mongoDB). I need 
something like that. 
/* Some thing like the above list contains All contents of the 
"PreviewSize" data <ImageName> & <BinaryData>.*/
```

First i tried with by casting by (BasicDBObject), but i gave me a error like,
`cannot cast (BasicBSONList) to (BasicDBObject)` Then i changed it to `(BasicBSONList)`

I think i am doing wrong in the receiver. What receiver i should use!!!???

I tried the above one, and the error message i got in the console is,

**Console Display:**

```
Result Size: 2
{ "PreviewSize" : [ { "ImageName" : "tom_and_jerry_guns.jpg" , "BinaryImage" : <Binary Data>} , 

{ "ImageName" : "Tom_and_Jerry,_Cartoons.jpg" , "BinaryImage" : <Binary Data>} , 

{ "ImageName" : "TomJerry2_468x342.jpg" , "BinaryImage" : <Binary Data>} , 

{ "ImageName" : "tom_and_jerry-5405.jpg" , "BinaryImage" : <Binary Data>}] , 

"_id" : { "$oid" : "4cef03b44613b5ba2d51a7b8"}}

"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
BasicBSONList can only work with numeric keys, not: [ImageName]"
```

I am totally new to mongoDB, like 3 days old :( .... Give me a way 
out!!!!

And, i also want to know is there any way to retrieve specific data, 
Like, if i know the any `ImageName` can i get its `BinaryData??`

Comment: Why nobody answering me? Is the question is not understandable? There are no comments also!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The query should be something like:

`db.albums.find({ "ThumbSize.ImageName" : "TomJerry2_468x342.jpg"} )`

That will return the Album document with all of the binary data.

You will not be able to return just that one piece. However, you can just return the "Thumbsize array" using the following.

`db.albums.find({ "ThumbSize.ImageName" : "TomJerry2_468x342.jpg"}, { "ThumbSize" : 1 } )`

However, if you have several large images, you'll want to look at GridFS for storing those images and then make  a .

Comment: I was searching for this in google for 3 days. All places I can see the queries like you have given. I am using java. And i am a newbie. Just now i updated the question. Please have a look at it!!!

Comment: Please take a look at your error message. It's clearly happening here: `(String) ((BasicDBList)result.get("PreviewSize")).get("ImageName");`. You're trying to call `.get("ImageName")` on a List object. The object is an array in JSON. Clearly you don't want "ImageName", you want something like `.get(0).get("ImageName")`. It is best that re-read and understand the error message.